# Remote Tunnel stuck at creating VSCode server

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I cannot create a new [Remote Tunnel](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/tunnels) on my remote machine.

It previously worked fine but after a reboot, it is now stuck at creating a new code server step.

```
code tunnel --log trace --cli-data-dir . --verbose
*
* Visual Studio Code Server
*
* By using the software, you agree to
* the Visual Studio Code Server License Terms (https://aka.ms/vscode-server-license) and
* the Microsoft Privacy Statement (https://privacy.microsoft.com/en-US/privacystatement).
*
[2023-01-08 16:58:40] debug No code server tunnel found, creating new one
```

The log in the working directory shows nothing. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft failed to mention a tiny detail about VSCode Tunnels which is bringing a myriad of weird problems to the users of this superb VSCode feature:

1. For VSCode Tunnels to run/connect properly on most Linux users, the **Server** VScode **MUST** run as *root*.
2. For VSCode Tunnels to run/connect properly on most Windows users, the **Server** VScode **MUST** *Run As Administrator*.

Works flawlessly after that.

Saved me a great ton of troubleshooting all my firewalls (local n remote), UDP port restrictions, OS Settings, "Hidden" VSCode Settings, etc... which I did quite extensively before stumbling upon this universal conclusion.

> > ALSO<<
> > Every time VScode is relaunched or stays on a long while, it sort of logs out of GitHub. I don't know why, but always be checking the account icon at the bottom left to see if there is a badge. If there is and if on hover it pops "Accounts - Sign in to Sync Settings", click on the icon then click "Sign in to sync settings".
> > They need to fix this!